# Android Java Login Activity Orientation Change

Tags: java, android, xml, authentication, android-orientation

I am using the default login_activity.xml from ADT and I would like it to change orientation when the device is flipped. I have a separate login_activity.xml in the res/layout-land directory because that seems to have solved similar problems that people have found.

Currently, the app loads the correct xml based on the orientation of the device at runtime. If you flip the device afterwards, the orientation changes, but the layout remains the same. Each xml has a different layout that looks better for its respective orientation.

I'm wondering if this is just not possible to do, or if I have overlooked a working fix.

I would post images of the actual running app, but I need 10 reputation before I can do that.

Below are my LoginActivity.java and activity_login.xml files:

```
//LoginActivity.java
/** Activity which displays a login screen to the user, offering registration as well.*/

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// Values for email and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String        mUsername;
private String        mPassword;

// UI references.
private EditText      mUsernameView;
private EditText      mPasswordView;
private View          mLoginFormView;
private View          mLoginStatusView;
private TextView      mLoginStatusMessageView;
private mDMI          app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    app = (mDMI) getApplication();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Set up the login form.
    mUsernameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mUsernameView.setText(mUsername);

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((id == R.id.login) || (id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL)) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    mLoginStatusMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status_message);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            attemptLogin();
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.getUniqueHardwareID).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String id = app.getDeviceId().getID();
            AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
            ad.setCancelable(false);
            ad.setTitle("Device ID");
            ad.setMessage("The Unqiue ID for this device is: \n" + id);
            ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", (Message) null);
            ad.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form. If there are form errors (invalid email,
 * missing fields, etc.), the errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mUsernameView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mUsername = mUsernameView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPassword)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (mPassword.length() < 4) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUsername)) {
        mUsernameView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mUsernameView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class); // hopefully this will switch to
                                                                                 // the
                                                                                 // MainActivity
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();

        mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);

    }
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}

}
```

Vertical Login Activity

```
//vertical activity_login.xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<!-- Login progress -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Login form -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/spashscreen" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/serverInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_address" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/getUniqueHardwareID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/show_device_id" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Make this uneditable if the mobile device has a value listed locally -->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</merge>
```

Horizontal Activity Login

```
//horizontal activity_login.xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<!-- Login progress -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Login form -->

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/spashscreen" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/serverInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_address" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/getUniqueHardwareID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/show_device_id" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Manifest for the given activity check if u have added orientation parameter to android:configChanges attribute. If yes remove it.